# Is there any way to hide attributes in a Rails Jbuilder template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-5, jbuilder

I know you can explicitly list fields like so,

```
json.(model, :field_one, :field_two, :field_three)
```

But is there anything similar to the following,

```
json.(model, except: :field_two)
```

which would output all of the model fields except the one called out?

Comment: Have you tried `json.merge! model.attributes.except("field_one", "field_two")`?

Comment: @mmichael that worked! Seems like there'd be an easier way ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `json.merge! model.attributes.except("field_one", "field_two")`

Answer (score 1):

I had done something like this.
Get an array of all desired attributes of model

```
model.attributes.keys.map { |key| key.to_sym } - [:field_one, :field_two]
```

Which can be written like

```
 model.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - [:field_one, :field_two]
```

Then splat the array while passing in jbuilder

```
json.(model, *(model.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - [:field_one, :field_two]))
```

Answer (score 1):

For non ActiveRecord objects this similar pattern works (Rails 4)

```
 json.merge! @some_object.as_json.except("not_this_one")
```

Answer (score 0):

This gem is what you need.

`json.except! @resource, :id, :updated_at`

https://github.com/chenqingspring/jbuilder-except